# AndroidManifest for Library Project in Android

Tags: android

I have a library project which has an Activity and can function as a separate Application as well. Now, Eclipse never did, but Android Studio is complaining about my App having two manifests with < application> tag, my main application and this library. Should I remove the tag from my library project, or is there a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should create two modules, one for your test Application, one for your library implementation.

Comment: The modules are separate, but both the modules have the <application> tag, which makes studio complain.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the application tag from your library project.

Here is an AndroidManifest.xml file of play-service lib.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4242030"
    android:versionName="4.2.42 (1018832-030)" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

</manifest>
```

As you can see that there is no application tag init.

Comment: What if I want to use this library as an application in itself? And any idea why eclipse never had this complain while studio does?

Comment: I think this issue is coming because the latest version of Android studio 1.3 , just yesterday one of my client report the same issue you asked in the question.

Comment: Ah, I have Android Studio 1.3 too. Looking for a possible work around. Somebody else is developing the library while I work on the application, and our library is actually an application which we intend to use as a library in one of our projects.

Comment: Well then I guess now its time to remove <application> tag from lib-manifest file.